# Who has to take care of wildcard handling in the following scp example?

Tags: c, scp

So I am trying to modify an existing scp server/client code and I came across this conceptual question. **If scp is being initiated in Machine A to copy multiple files from Machine B to Machine A,**
Whose code is meant to handle the wildcard ? Is the client code in Machine A simply supposed to pass the path string with wildcard as it is to the server daemon in machine B ? Is there a radical change required in client code in handling multiple downloads due to wildcard ?

Any references to existing scp client code would be useful !

Answer (score 0):

The wild-cards are expanded by the shell. When using scp it is not likely (impossible?) this will happen for the source argument. If the destination argument is your local machine, than wild-cards are likely to cause your shell to glob for files.

Without wild-card expansion occuring, the argument is passed litterally into scp.
I highly doubt scp would do any globbing or wild-card expansion - that is most likely handled by the shell. scp uses ssh in the background but there is a lot going on besides and I'm certainly not the expert.

In a nut-shell, machine B would handle the wildcards and glob for files - whether this is done by the shell in machine B or by scp I would not know.